# Geometry Nodes: Curve is acting weird when spinning on Z axis

Tags: animation, geometry-nodes

I'm very new to geometry nodes and want to make a seamless looping animation of a road with dashed traffic lines down the center. I was able to create this road very easily using geometry nodes, but when I animate (I parent the road to an empty in the center, and just spin the empty) it, I notice something is "off," mainly because the dashed lines give it away.

Here is an animated GIF demonstrating the issue. It's a 76 frame loop, and what should be happening is these two frames should look fairly similar. In the 2nd frame, notice the top of the curve and how it "shifts" just a tiny bit.
[image]

I'm not sure why this curve would be shifting at all, as it appears to be a perfect circle? Here is my node setup:

[image]

Any idea what I may be doing wrong?

Edit: took a look at the curve in Edit mode, and noticed this gap between two vertices. I'm not sure how it got there, and I'm not able to use "F" to make a segment.

[image]

**[link to blend file](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/bin186oc3wousj2iye19n/curve_issue.blend?rlkey=rl63tv1rzbbnhl82zpzcgulsq&dl=0)**

Comment: Hi GoroToro, your node setup is fine. So the issue could be hiding somewhere else. As we are not able to guess all possible reasons for this to happen, could you please include additional information like: screenshots of your Input curve in edit mode, the Outliner, Animation editor or even better - the blend file itself.

Comment: @RumenBelev Just updated the original post with another image. Looks like there's a gap, but not sure how it got there.

Comment: Hi GoroToro, I've inspected your file and it seems your circle is not quite circular. There is a subtle offset. What I suggest is to create a new curve by creating a Mesh circle with 144 vertices and Convert it to Curve. Then If you still want to use your object just replace its Curve Data with the Circle's Curve Data (which should have name "Circle") and that will fix the problem. You still may need to adjust the scale of the curve in Edit mode.

Comment: @RumenBelev Thanks, that worked!